# How can I access dynamic Checkboxes

Tags: vb.net-2010

Hey Guys I created some Checkboxed dynamicly and now I want to set their value to False. My Problem is I can't access them because the Name is not stated.

I created them this way:

```vb
        For j = 0 To column - 1

        For i = 0 To row - 1
            MyCheckboxes(counter) = New CheckBox
            MyCheckboxes(counter).Visible = True
            MyCheckboxes(counter).Checked = True
            MyCheckboxes(counter).Text = ""
            MyCheckboxes(counter).Size = New Size(15, 14)
            MyCheckboxes(counter).Name = "Check" + counter.ToString
            Me.Controls.Add(MyCheckboxes(counter))
            MyCheckboxes(counter).Location = New Point(Xpos, Ypos)
            Xpos = Xpos + 20
            counter = counter + 1
        Next i
        Ypos = Ypos + 20
        Xpos = 160
    Next j
```

into a global array

```vb
   Public MyCheckboxes() As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
```

Now I want to set the values to False in a Button on click event:

```vb
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim i As Integer = 0


    Me.Controls("Check" & i).Checked = False 'Here it says: Checked is not a Member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'
    CheckBox0.Checked = False ' Here it says CheckBox0 is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.


End Sub
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong I searched for a reason for nearly 3 hours. Please help me
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just access them through your array.

```
MyCheckboxes(i).Checked = False
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working: 'NullReferenceExeption was unhandled' Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: So... what's the value of `i`?

Comment: What does `counter` start at when you're building the checkboxes?

Comment: counter starts at zero aswell and is increased every loop of the inner loop. So there is definitely a field MyCheckboxes(0). I checked it with the debugger aswell.

Comment: @McFatigue: If there's *definitely* a `MyCheckboxes(0)`, your `NullReferenceException` comes from elsewhere. Which line is highlighted?

Comment: MyCheckboxes(0).Checked = False 'its exactly in this line highlighted. I checkt it with the debugger and MyCheckboxes(0) is filled

Comment: @McFatigue: Then that's completely impossible. Sorry. There must be something you're missing. If `MyCheckboxes(0)` is something, it's not `Nothing`.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your help minitech! I solved it know you were right. I did a mistake by the global array. I created a new local array to create the boxes and havn't used the global and I havn't checkt the value of it at the right position. Thank you very much!